# System requirement to run C# window desktop application

Tags: c#

Is it necessary to install .net framework to run c# window desktop application on client machine ?

Answer (score 1):

If your desktop application using .NET library then .NET framework need to be installed on client machine.

Answer (score 1):

In general yes but latest versions of Windows have some versions .NET Framework preinstalled:

```
.NET Framework 3.0: Windows Vista
.NET Framework 4.0: Windows 8
.NET Framework 4.5: Windows 8
.NET Framework 4.6: Windows 10
```

If your application needs another version, you still have to install it.